# JsTree and Laravel Trouble

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, jstree

I'm following this [guide](http://mackhankins.com/blog/lazy-loading-with-jstree-and-laravel) to setup JsTree with lazy load using Ajax in my Laravel 5.5 app .

This is my controller: https://gist.github.com/aaronr0207/7fa0a38f40bfd2f728a15d655254f82d

My View:
https://gist.github.com/aaronr0207/f87720263e3d6026b04b00c08bae5cb2

My JsTree class is exactly the same I didn't make any change.

Actually I'm getting the following error on chrome's console:

> d9973d3e-1476-4453-a013-9e9c8430bcba:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined

[image]

But when I dump the response to debug it (at the end of TreeViewController data method):

```
        dd(response()->json($tree->build()));
```

It works...

[image]

My response looks like this (when I die-dump it):

[image]

Any idea? Thank you

**EDIT1**: If I return a simple `json_encode($tree->build)` there are no errors but it shows an empty tree... and the response looks like this:

[image]

**EDIT2**: got it! But now there are a new issue... All I did to solve it was change the url string with a callback:

```
 $('#jstree').jstree({
    'core': {
        'data': {
            'url': function (node) {
                return '{!! route('tree.data') !!}' ;
            },
            'data': function (node) {
                console.log(node);
                return {'id': node.id};
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But now when I fetch next level directories, if they have another directorie inside it fails without error:

[image]

Test1 content is the following:

[image]

If I delete test1/test2 folder, it works showing:

[image]

Same when I delete the txt file...What is happening now? Maybe this is a new question so I'll post my solution to the main problem and I'll accept it.

Comment: What response do you get when you call the api manually with an `id` parameter set to `uploads/general/test1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it! All I did to solve it was change the url string with a callback:

```
$('#jstree').jstree({
    'core': {
        'data': {
            'url': function (node) {
                return '{!! route('tree.data') !!}' ;
            },
            'data': function (node) {
                console.log(node);
                return {'id': node.id};
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your named route is not working correctly. In your `TreeController.php`, change the route `tree/route` as follows:

```
Route::get('tree/route', 'TreeController@data')->name('tree.data');
```

Comment: Just test it, same result

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by the escaping in the response. Can you `dd($request->id)` when the id is set?